# How to link opposite values of two buttons using ipywidgets in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipywidgets

How do I link the value of two buttons to be opposite of one another? The widgets.jslink() function only seems to link the value to be the same, not the opposite. I know that I could use widgets.ToggleButtons() to link two buttons, but I want the success button to be green and the fail button to be red. ToggleButtons() does not appear to allow different coloring for each button. If it does, I'm open to that as a solution, as well. Here is the code I have so far (FYI: I'm running this code in JupyterLab using ipywidgets and node.js):

```
button_y= widgets.Button(
    description='Success',
    disabled=False,
    button_style='success'
    tooltip='Click me',
    icon='check'
)

button_n= widgets.Button(
    description='Failure',
    disabled=False,
    button_style='danger'
    tooltip='Click me',
    icon='check'
)

display(widgets.HBox((button_y, button_n)))
```

Output:

[image: two buttons output]

Answer (score 1):

Guessing that you want to link the `disabled` attributes.
You can use the [`observe` method](https://traitlets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using_traitlets.html) in the backend to add logic to links:

```
def toggle_button_n(value):
    button_n.disabled = not value.new

def toggle_button_y(value):
    button_y.disabled = not value.new

button_n.observe(toggle_button_y, names=['disabled'])
button_y.observe(toggle_button_n, names=['disabled'])
```

You also need to change the initialisation so that only one of the buttons is enabled.